# Importing data from a web service as a layer in CartoDB

Tags: carto

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to bring web services into CartoDB as a layer. In particular, I'm currently trying to import an ArcGIS Feature Service: http://data.nconemap.gov/geoportal/catalog/search/resource/details.page?uuid=%7B20945466-5E79-458C-AB52-5E2899961E45%7D

I'm sure there ought to be some way of doing this, but I can't figure out how...

Comment: It might be doable with ogr2ogr http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html. See the shapefile example from http://www.gdal.org/drv_cartodb.html. Unfortunately GDAL can't read data from ESRI Feature Service but perhaps you can use the same service as WFS and use WFS driver http://www.gdal.org/drv_wfs.html.

Answer (score 2):

CartoDB had some issues with the ArcGIS connector that seemed to be solved last week. You can use these URL in order to import the three layers of the [FeatureServer](http://services.nconemap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NC1Map_Parcels/FeatureServer):

http://services.nconemap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NC1Map_Parcels/FeatureServer/0
http://services.nconemap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NC1Map_Parcels/FeatureServer/1
http://services.nconemap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NC1Map_Parcels/FeatureServer/2

as the layers are:

- County Boundaries (0)
- Parcel Centroids (1)
- Parcels (2)

Notice that for this you'd need to have the ArcGIS connector enabled in your account. Contact support@cartodb.com if you haven't!